# Does in 3-tier architecture the code stores in application layer or DB layer?

Tags: architecture, 3-tier

I want to know where do the executable files resides? If it is in DB layer does that mean every time it loads from there and executes? And is it same for all 3-tier architecture ??

Answer (score 1):

Each tier of a 3-tier (or n-tier) architecture has code / logic in it.  Each of the tiers are separate, and although you *could* load your code from a different tier (like a web browser loading html/javascript from the application serve), the execution of that code happens on the relevant tier.  The loading of the code is not the important bit, it's the executing of it that determines the "tier".